# How to set border at bottom for linear layout programactically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I want to set thick border color at bottom of linear layout programmatically. I have found many codes but I couldn't get what I need.

Code:

```
LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
li.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Either user a shape drawable with bottom border, or add a view with 1dp height at last in the linear layout.

Comment: add view in xml file...then set the visibility of the border view programatically.

Comment: how can i set view for linear layout programtically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create the xml file (Border.xml) in Drawable folder for Creating border like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetTop="-2dp"
    android:insetRight="-2dp"
    android:insetLeft="-2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/ora" />
        <solid android:color="#D3000000" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

And set the Background dynamically by using this line.

```
li.setBackgroundDrawable(R.Drawable.Border);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot priya for save my time. I am looking for like this to display in Textview.

Comment: yes , I used in my code yar it's perfectly worked well thanks.

Comment: @kanimozhi you can't upvote prior to get 50 rep. But you can accept by clicking the white checkmark near the question.